# c# LinQ to xml more then one where

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Can anyone help me with this code I don't know what is wrong here.. I want to retrieve Data from XML where Date is 2015/9/12 and 2015/9/13.

```
        var events = (from item in xdocument.Descendants("Event")
                      where (string)item.Element("Date") == "2015/9/12" &&
                      (string)item.Element("Date") == "2015/9/13"
                      select (string)item.Element("Date")).ToList();
        foreach (string name in events)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(name);
        }
```

Here is my XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Events>
  <Event ID="0">
    <Name>test</Name>
    <Date>2015/9/12</Date>
    <Priority>0</Priority>
    <Created_at>0000</Created_at>
  </Event>
  <Event ID="1">
    <Name>test1</Name>
    <Date>2015/9/13</Date>
    <Priority>0</Priority>
    <Created_at>0000</Created_at>
  </Event>
  <Event ID="2">
    <Name>test2</Name>
    <Date>2015/9/15</Date>
    <Priority>2</Priority>
    <Created_at>0000</Created_at>
  </Event>
</Events>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you need to do is modify your xml. You have tag mismatches on your date tags. You have `<Date>2015/9/12</Data>`. Notice your ending tag says Data instead of Date. Then you can do the following:

```
var events = doc.Descendants("Event").Where(x => x.Element("Date").Value == "2015/9/12" || x.Element("Date").Value == "2015/9/13");
```

Comment: Thank you very much. On the begining I was using the Where(x => x.Element("Date").Value == "2015/9/12") but I did not know that you can use logic in it like "&& and ||". It's hard to find good tutarial for the linq to xml.. The XML file was mine faul I did it wrong on website I was using <data> tag on first and wanted to change them here for Date but as allways I failed with my cleaver edditing :)

Comment: No problem. Trying to build my rep up, could you please up-vote me.

Comment: I am new here need more reputation for that :(